# Using Azure CLI to create managed instance via bash

Tags: bash, azure, azure-devops

I am currently working on creating a bash script to automate azure managed sql instances. This is my current script:

```
export admin=<admin>
export password=<password>

az network vnet create \
  --name <name> \
  --resource-group <group-name> \
  --subnet-name <subnet-name>

az sql mi create -n <mi-name> -u $admin -p $password \
            --resource-group <group> -l "eastus" \
            --vnet-name <vnet-name> --subnet <rs-subnet> \
```

I am getting the following error

Deployment failed. Correlation ID: b3695d70-9175-4796-8280-e6c773e76213. . (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=871071)

When you go to the page it says to configure the existing virtual network but they provide a powershell script and i'd like to use bash if that is the problem. Could someone help me convert the script to bash?

If the problem is something else please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure what <rs-subnet> is.  When you create the Vnet you are calling --subnet-name <subnet-name> but it looks like you are using a different subnet name in the mi create.

Comment: See the article [Create Azure SQL Managed Instance using Azure CLI](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2018/11/14/create-azure-sql-managed-instance-using-azure-cli/).

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate your help

Comment: @mshah49rs You could [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it is useful that will help more communities who have the same issue.

Comment: I accepted the answer sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per our [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/sql/mi?view=azure-cli-latest#az-sql-mi-create) for `az sql mi create` you need to supply the Name or ID of the subnet that allows access to an Azure Sql Managed Instance. If subnet name is provided, `--vnet-name` must be provided.

Something like this:

```
az sql mi create -g $rg -n $miname -l  $LOCATION -i -u $admin  -p $password --vnet-name $vnet --subnet $snet
```

You also need to ensure you have created a route table in the VNet.  See
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2018/03/14/how-to-configure-network-for-azure-sql-managed-instance/

```
az network vnet create \
  --name $vnet \
  --resource-group $rg \
  --subnet-name $snet

az network route-table create -g $rg  -n MyRouteTable

az network route-table route create -g $rg --route-table-name MyRouteTable -n MiRoute \
   --next-hop-type Internet --address-prefix 0.0.0.0/0

az network vnet subnet update \
  --vnet-name $vnet  \
  --name $snet \
  --resource-group $rg \
  --route-table MyRouteTable
```